# multiple lines of text with bold headings in android

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I want to write 2 pages of text  which includes multiple paragraphs with some bullet points and some contact numbers. 
please help me with some reference tutorial or code. I tried with textview but it is not that effective. please suggest me effective solution for this?

my xml file:

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/simpleTextView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="All text here"
android:textSize="20sp"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
```

Comment: use html text with all html tags using textview

Comment: here is some text formatting example http://androidcocktail.blogspot.in/2014/03/android-spannablestring-example.html

Comment: @sushildlh can you provide some example or reference code for this?

Comment: already given in answers by others just refer

Comment: @Kamlesh , i was your profile. why don't you accept any answer ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this the example of html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Unordered List with Square Bullets</h2>

<ul style="list-style-type:square">
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

place the above code in strings.xml file with some name example htmlString

and use it like this

```
 textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.htmlString)));
```

Output will be like this

```
Unordered List with Square Bullets    
 - Coffee
 - Tea
 - Milk
```

else you have to use webView and load the html page into webview will be very efficient

Answer (score 1):

You can format your text as html and use the following function to render the html(with the format) to you textview.

< Android Nougat:

```
yourTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<h2>Title</h2><br><p>Description here</p>"));
```

>= Android Nougat:

```
yourTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<h2>Title</h2><br><p>Description here</p>", Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT));
```

To distinguish between Android versions use

`Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N.`

Answer (score 0):

Save your HTML text to strings.xml file and then access them into your class and setText fromHtml as follows

```
 textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.app_name)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fromHtml` to make the text as HTML

Use below code to get resulted text:

```
public static Spanned fromHtml(String html) {
        Spanned result;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            result = Html.fromHtml(html, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
        } else {
            result = Html.fromHtml(html);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Use it in your code like:

> your_text_view.setText(fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.htmlText)));

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using textViews with html, we can use webviews for more effective result.

res/values/strings.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">TestProject2</string>

    <string name="html">
        <![CDATA[
        <h1>Big Title</h1>
        <p>UL list:
        <ul>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
        </ul>
        <p>OL list:
        <ol>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
        </ol>
        ]]>
    </string>
</resources>
```

Layout file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              tools:context=".MainActivity"
              android:orientation="vertical">

<WebView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity looks like this:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
String htmlAsString = getString(R.string.html); 
Spanned htmlAsSpanned = Html.fromHtml(htmlAsString);      
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, htmlAsString, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
}
```